# NoModificationAllowedError in Firefox when using DnD events

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop, draggable

Using some basic drag'n'drop features and i keep getting this message in Firefox, works well in Chrome though.

`NoModificationAllowedError: Modifications are not allowed for this document`

This happens when i try to use the `clearData()` function on the event when the `ondrop` event is fired.

HTML:

```
<!-- draggable element -->
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
<!-- dropzone element -->
<div ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondragenter="onDragEnter(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div>
```

JS:

```
function onDragStart(event) {
    event
        .dataTransfer
        .setData('text/plain', 'test');
}
function onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
function onDragEnter(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // polyfill fix
}
function onDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event
        .currentTarget
        .parentNode
        .classList.add("dropped");
    event
        .dataTransfer
        .clearData(); //<---- This is where it fails
}
```

So yeah no idea how to fix this, and i need to clear the data as i set/reset some variable and internal params using it (code omitted). Works well in chrome (even IE)

Comment: [`DataTransfer.clearData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/clearData): _"This method can **only be used** in the handler for the **`dragstart` event**, because that's the **only time** the drag operation's data store is **writeable**."_

Comment: Yes unfortunately you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use Cleardata() method in OnDragStart and not use it in OnDrop() Method.

```
onDragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.clearData();
    event
        .dataTransfer
        .setData('text/plain', event.target.dataset.item);
}
```

Must user text/plain.
Must use preventDefault() while dropping.

```
onDragOver(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Must use preventDefault inside onDrop Method like that.

```
 onDrop(event) {
        const id = event
            .dataTransfer
            .getData('text');
        const draggableElement = '';
        event.preventDefault();
        this.template.querySelectorAll('.example-draggable').forEach(element => {
            if (element.innerHTML == id) {
                this.draggableElement = element;
            }
        });;
        if ((!event.target.innerText.includes('Drag From Here')) && (!event.target.innerText.includes('Drop Here'))) {
            const bar = event.target.parentElement;
            bar.appendChild(this.draggableElement);
        }
        else {

            const bar = event.target;
            bar.appendChild(this.draggableElement);

        }


    }
```

here i use preventdefault in middle of the code that will prevent reloading of the page while appending element.

Comment: Note that "Must user text/plain" advice is good if you want to be able to drag from one website to another, but that it is not exactly necessary within a single site/application (and it is useful to exclude to prevent dragging from one website to another). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types#dragging_custom_data